# Firebase emulators set database target

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

### Setting

I am developing on a test Firestore instance hosted on firebase, and I would like to run `firebase emulators:start` targeting this database. Currently it's targeting an emulator suite accessible through `localhost:4000`. In the codebase, I have initialized `firebase` instance with parameters for the actual instance as follows:

```
const fireAdmin = admin.initializeApp({
      credential   : admin.credential.applicationDefault() 
    , databaseURL  : DatabaseConfig['databaseURL']
    , storageBucket: DatabaseConfig['storageBucket']
});
```

where `DatabaseConfig = { databaseURL: "https://mytestingserversite.firebaseio.com", ... }`.

### Problem

However, the functions are still writing/reading from the emulator instance. This is my `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing some `env` variable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [databaseURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.AppOptions#optional-databaseurl) parameter isn't really doing something here, as it is for specifying the Realtime Database URL.

Regardless of which emulator you are actually using, you can omit the **Firestore** emulator by just running the emulators you want.

For instance: `firebase emulators:run --only functions,hosting`

That should tell the CLI to use the actual **Firestore** instance in the Cloud and not the emulator.